# Horse jumping off the cliff scene from 'The Revenant'

Tags: film-techniques, effects, the-revenant

In the movie The Revenant, when Di Caprio jumps off the cliff while on his horse, the scene looks very realistic. While in the "fight with the bear" scene I could definitely tell that it was done with help of CGI, the horse jump looked a lot more realistic.

How did they film it?

Comment: Would a horse willingly jump off a cliff?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The horse-off-the-cliff scene was created with the help of Industrial Light & Magic per [this interview](http://www.studiodaily.com/2016/02/vfx-supervisor-richard-mcbride-on-the-revenant/) with the film's visual effects supervisor.

[This clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbeKX28AgK4) (which I believe was aired during Academy Awards) shows a brief glimpse of how the scene was put together. Essentially, a stunt man rode a motorized mock-up horse over an embankment and jumped off, landing on an inflatable, and then CGI was used to add realism.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

There was a brief behind-the-scenes snippet from that scene during the Academy Awards, when they were announcing the nominees for Best Visual Effects.  It appears that a fake horse and a blue screen were used.  There's a copy of the ceremony on YouTube, but the video quality is very poor.  The snippet begins at [43m18s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKDBtv-z5Ds&t=2598).